# how to create snippet in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

```
<snippet>
    <content>
        <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
        <style type = "text/css">

        </style>
</head>

<body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">

        </script>
</body>

</html>
    </content>
    <tabTrigger>html_t</tabTrigger>
    <description>html_css_javascript</description>
    <scope>html</scope>
</snippet>
```

when i save it as h.sublime-snippet, I get the error "No content for Snippet Packages /User/h.sublime-snippet"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <!-- <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger> -->
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

If you compare yours to the code in this example, you will see that yours is missing some key components -- e.g., `<![CDATA[` then your html code and then `]]>`

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to make a snippet(html comment), triggered by tapping c+tab :

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA <!-- ${1:comment} -->]</content>
    <!-- Optional: Tab trigger to activate the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>c</tabTrigger>
    <description>Snippet to make fast html comment</description>
</snippet>
```